# Not able to display value after selecting from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have a input field where the user can type normally. Just beside the field there is an arrow

[image]

on click of that arrow a dropdown will get open that contains list of data.

[image]

Now when the user clicks on any of the values in the dropdown list that should get displayed in the input field

[image]

This selected value can be edited by the user as it will be treated as a normal input value.

The issue at my end is that when i select the value from dropdown it is coming like this
[image]

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" value="" id="job" placeholder="Job title" class="form-control title"  name="job">
<button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default toggle-dropdown pj-dropdown-menu pj-jobtitle" data-toggle="dropdown"  name="job_title" id="job_title">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_value" data-bind="bs-drp-sel-value" value="">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu line pj-dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
 <li  class="line" >
    <a href="#">
       <span class="developer">Frontend Developer </span>
       <p class="years">12 yrs</p>
       <div class="san-francisco-calif">
          SanFrancisco california USA  
          <p class="hour"> $24/hour</p>
       </div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li  class="line">
    <a href="#">
       <span class="developer">Backend Developer </span>
       <p class="years">12 yrs</p>
       <div class="san-francisco-calif">
          SanFrancisco california USA  
          <p class="hour"> $24/hour</p>
       </div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li  class="line" >
    <a href="#">
       <span class="developer">Business Consultant </span>
       <p class="years">12 yrs</p>
       <div class="san-francisco-calif">
          SanFrancisco california USA  
          <p class="hour"> $24/hour</p>
       </div>
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Script Code

```
<script>
 $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){    
     $('.toggle-dropdown').html($(this).find('span').html() + '<span class="caret"></span>');    
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this script.

```
<script>
 $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){    
    $("#job").val($(this).find("span").text());    
 })
</script>
```

On click of a tag simply find the inner span's text and assign that as a value in a text box with ID #job.

Comment: @ Smit Raval thank you its working ,but i need to show the dropdown list below the input box. can u please help me.

Comment: Can you please explain I didn't get it? @lakshmipriya